# Android emulator craches when Using SmsManager to send SMS

Tags: android, android-emulator

I click on send button in my app and emulator craches with following error message :

> HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
>   dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _utf8_write
>     Referenced from: /Users/Nabil/Documents/Development/Android/sdk/tools/emulator64-x86
>     Expected in: flat namespace
>   dyld: Symbol not found: _utf8_write
>     Referenced from: /Users/Nabil/Documents/Development/Android/sdk/tools/emulator64-x86
>     Expected in: flat namespace

Here is my class code :

```
public void Send (View view){
        txtnum = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNum);
        txtmsg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
        String phoneNo = txtnum.getText().toString();
        String message = txtmsg.getText().toString();

        try {

            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "SMS faild, please try again.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and my manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: Your code and manifest look correct. What kind of machine is the emulator running on?

Comment: Try to run your app in real device.

Comment: Mike i'm using nexus one

Comment: @NabilElAtlas Actually, I meant your computer. It seems to be a [bug in the emulator](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=91681), on Macs at least.

Comment: i have a mac os yosemite 10.10.1

Answer (score -1):

First know android simulators are not real devices. Use any real devices, because real devices only interact with hardware config(Sim Card).

Comment: it is not necessary to add sim in order to check messaging app in emulator we can do that